# How to get raindrop.io to open youtube videos in youtube vanced instead of the official app?

Tags: youtube, share-menu

Is there a way to make apps open to specific apps we choose always?

Comment: it should ask the first tome you try, and to reset it so it asks again you can go into the youtube (non-vanced) app settings and clear opening defaults

Comment: On Android 8.1.0 (and higher?) this is also accessible from Settings -> Apps & Notifications -> Default Apps -> App Links where it seems to list all apps that can open links.